Box.new not showing on lower timeframe
I am trying to make box.new from a higher timeframe to the current timeframe.
I wrote the following code for plotting weekly box on daily but its not happening.
It is working fine on the same (weekly) timeframe.
I also tried to use the drawBox Function in security function, that does not work.
Help appreciated!
//@version=5
indicator("SR (NEW)", "SR (NEW)", true, max_lines_count = 500)

// Getting the bar values
type OHLC
    float o
    float h
    float l
    float c
    // float prevC

makeOHLC(int bb = 0)=>
    OHLC.new(open[bb], high[bb], low[bb], close[bb])


ibar = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "W", makeOHLC(0), lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

// Drawing box
drawBox(left, right, top, bottom, diff, extend = extend.right) =>
    drawnBox = box.new(left, top, right, bottom, extend = extend)
    if diff == "res"
        box.set_border_color(drawnBox, #f4433666)
        box.set_bgcolor(drawnBox, #f4433633)
    else 
        box.set_border_color(drawnBox, #00968866)
        box.set_bgcolor(drawnBox, #00968833)
    drawnBox



// Intermediate Timeframe
isrc = (ibar.h - ibar.l) / 2 > math.abs(ibar.o - ibar.c)
ibullCandle                       = (ibar.c > ibar.o and not isrc)
ibearCandle                       = (ibar.o > ibar.c and not isrc)

ibull1ContiSupp                   = ibullCandle[1] and isrc[2] and ibullCandle[3]


if ibull1ContiSupp
    drawBox(bar_index[2], last_bar_index, ibar.h[2], ibar.l[2], "sup")

I also want to remove the boxes whos lows have been broken

Add a debugging amount of log to your script and check the box coordinates manually.

Ok. Will learn it (still learning this language), implement it and see. Thank you.

@karatedog
I tried to learn logging but I don't think I did well :(
I would appreciate it if you could help me with it.

Did you try log.info(str.tostring(<put your box coordinates here>)) and then open Log?
